# Restrict category by age

Tags: php, categories, restriction

I want to restrict a certain category number by age from userprofile. Note that the age is being added by typing a number not by selecting day, month and year.

Here is the code for editing the profie:

```
tr("Age", "<input type=\"text\" name=\"age\" size=25 value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($CURUSER["age"]) . "\" /> ", 1);
```

Here is the code from the userprofile:

```
if ($user["age"])
    print("<tr><td class=rowhead>Age</td><td align=left>$user[age]</td></tr>\n");
```

I found this code on the internet and I was wondering if it can be adjusted for my needs. This code works but not properly with the age it restricts the view but for 25 years (I think that it's something with the birthday requiring day, month and year while my script requires entering age by typing the number.)

```
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
if (!$row) 
    stderr($lang['error'], $lang['invalid_id']); 

$birthday = $CURUSER["birthday"]; 
$birthday = date("U", strtotime($birthday)); 
if ($row['category'] == 15 && $CURUSER[birthday] != "0000-00-00" && (date("U") - $birthday) <  567648000) { 
stderr($lang['error'], "You are too young to view this category!"); 
}
```

I need users that are under 18 years to not have rights to view this category.

*note 15 is the category number that needs restriction.

**edit:**

confirmprofileedition.php

```
$age = $_POST["age"];
$updateset[] = "age = '$age'";
```

Comment: What is the format of your `age` field?

Comment: uh.. sorry for the question but where can I find the format?

Comment: Does `$user["age"]` output a number value such as `18` or does it output a timestamp?

Comment: it outputs number value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source](http://pastebin.com/ipKAFmTe) you provided, and assuming `age` is a number and not calculated by a timestamp:

```
if ($row["category"] == 15 && $user["age"] < 18) {
    stderr($lang["error"], "You are too young to view this category!"); 
} else {
    // Show regular content
}
```

Comment: What about the category? I have multiple categories and I need to restrict one that has an id 15

Comment: I cannot see your full source, but if the variable `$row` does indeed fetch the `category` field, you can use my answer above.

Comment: also how can I add text to show saying 'You are too young to view this page' when the user is under 18 years? I also edited my 1st post that's the last file that has age in it.

Comment: Can you link to the full source using what I've provided? You can use a tool like PasteBin.

To add text will depend on how your application is set up. If it isn't an MVC system, you can probably use `echo "You are too young to view this page";`

Comment: `//` denotes a comment, try adding outputting the text using `echo` from the previous comment.

Comment: Just want to point that the code I gave in my 1st post works, it restricts me from viewing the category I want, but it's not accurate in age. Probably has something to do that it requires date, month and year, while my script is requires only typing...

Comment: can you input the text? I'm new to php and don't know where exactly to put it

Comment: the code is restricting me while I have entered bigger number than 18 in my profile, atleast it works with restricting. now it has to recognize the age number entered in the user's profile

Comment: It looks as if `$user` isn't defined in the source you provided - do you know if `age` is a field in the `users` table? If it is, you'll need to update the select query.

Comment: Cheers mate thanks for the help I needed to change: if ($row["category"] == 15 && $user["age"] < 18) to if ($row["category"] == 15 && $CURUSER[age] < 18) and it worked. Just one last question how can I make a the You are not young text appear without this: stderr($lang['error'], ?

Comment: Replace it with `echo "You are too young to view this category!";`

Comment: I did that and it showed me the category with the 'you are not young' text at the top left of my page

Comment: Move that entire code block further down the source to adjust where it shows up.